# Mask UIImage iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use to mask uiimages in iOS 7, using following code, which works great. But now, in iOS 8 it doesn't do anything, instead of returning me the original image + mask, it returns me a black image.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

CGImageRef imgRef = [image CGImage];
CGImageRef maskRef = [maskImage CGImage];
CGImageRef actualMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                          CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);
CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imgRef, actualMask);
return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
```

}

Here is how my app works:
- original image is going to be blurred
- then a mask is applied (circle, square, any shape. which is .png image)
- returns blurred image, and mask should crop the blurred image and see behind the original image without blur. it works on iOS 7, but in iOS 8 the code about masking (above) is not working. any ideas?

Comment: It is working for me on both platform, same result.

Comment: I Can't make it work on iOS 8 Simulator, and i don't know if works on real device. Maybe this just happens on Simulator?

Answer (score -1):

Use this method to mask the image in iOS 8.0. I have used this method in my running code as well and working fine.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef imgRef  = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef maskRef = [maskImage CGImage];


    int maskWidth      = CGImageGetWidth(maskRef);
    int maskHeight     = CGImageGetHeight(maskRef);
    //  round bytesPerRow to the nearest 16 bytes, for performance's sake
    int bytesPerRow    = (maskWidth + 15) & 0xfffffff0;
    int bufferSize     = bytesPerRow * maskHeight;

    //  allocate memory for the bits
    CFMutableDataRef dataBuffer = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFDataSetLength(dataBuffer, bufferSize);

    //  the data will be 8 bits per pixel, no alpha
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef ctx            = CGBitmapContextCreate(CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(dataBuffer),
                                                        maskWidth, maskHeight,
                                                        8, bytesPerRow, colourSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    //  drawing into this context will draw into the dataBuffer.
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, maskWidth, maskHeight), maskRef);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    //  now make a mask from the data.
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(dataBuffer);
    CGImageRef mask                 = CGImageMaskCreate(maskWidth, maskHeight, 8, 8, bytesPerRow,
                                                        dataProvider, NULL, FALSE);

    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);
    CFRelease(dataBuffer);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imgRef, mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```